# Get notified about new files on SFTP server

Tags: bash, software-recommendation, notification, sftp, expect

I am looking for any solution for my problem. I have SFTP access to client's server and I need some script or something else to watch after new files because they are added irregularly. I need this functionality:

When there is a new file on server the script in best case sends an email (but i will be thankful for any other kind of notification).

I can have only SFTP - so no ssh etc... Do you know about anything like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not content with other solutions so I wrote my own script in python which will walk through remote filesystem, saves filepath to database and sends me an email about new entries. You can [get it on GitHub](https://github.com/honza-kasik/check-for-files)!

Answer (score 2):

Given http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sftp.1.html

- use the `-b` option to pass in sftp commands to cd to the remote directory, and list the files (use `ls -l` or `ls -1t`)

  - you'll need to set up ssh keys for password-less authentication
- parse that output to look for new files
- use sftp again to get the new files.

Use cron to schedule this job every N minutes or hours

Comment: Thanks, this look great. But there is a small problem - this only gets files from current directory but I need to get all files recursively from all subdirectories. I looked through that manpage but I did not find any hint how to do that.

Comment: Do you know what the directory hierarchy is? If not, unfortunately the sftp `ls` does not have a recursive option, so you have your work cut out for you parsing the ls output for files versus directories and descending into subdirectories programmatically. If you *do* know the dir structure, then you have to program the `cd somewhere; ls`

Comment: I only know how many levels I will have to descend. I'll have to create temporary batch file for sftp for each descending... But after all this sounds as a good solution. Thanks :).